# Rails: ExecJS::ProgramError, related to assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, execjs

I'm learning Rails by following a tutorial, and I ran into this problem where I want to link to an image with the assistance of assets pipeline like follows

```
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails logo"), 'http://somewebsite.com' %>
```

But, when loading the page it shows the following error ,
[image: ExecJS::Program Error]

note that I've deployed my app into Heroku, and it is working just fine !!

Also, I should add that I have experienced the same error before for a different problem and the fix (according to an answer here) was to change the application.html.erb from

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                          'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

to

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all',
                                          'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

and again both codes are working just fine with Heroku.

FYI, my machine is running Windows 10..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to downgrade your `coffee-script` gem because `coffee-script source >= 1.10.0` does not work well with Windows ([coffee-script-source Windows issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4158))

- add `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` to your gemfile
- do a bundle update from your CLI by running `bundle update coffee-script-source`

This worked for me when I was learning back on my Windows PC.